# Best traveling bags?

Tags: luggage, shopping

What are some good travel bags up to 23 kilos that can be found around Central Europe - Germany, Switzerland?

Comment: What kind of bag are you looking for if not a suitcase? Do you mean like a [backpacking backpack](http://www.buytravelbackpacks.com/images/backpack.jpg)? A big duffel bag?

Comment: I would recommend trying the [Migros at Marktgasse 46](https://filialen.migros.ch/de/Bern-Marktgasse/0034710). On the underground floor there's a dedicated travel aisle, you can expect to find these items there: [Bags](https://produkte.migros.ch/sortiment/supermarkt/bekleidung-accessoires/koffer-taschen-reisen/taschen) | [Backpacks / Daypacks](https://produkte.migros.ch/sortiment/supermarkt/bekleidung-accessoires/koffer-taschen-reisen/rucksaecke-kleintaschen). Prices aren't discount-level cheap, but affordable.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're really just looking for a temporary bag and want to spend as little as possible, you could try your luck at one of the various second-hand stores / thrift shops in Bern. Ask or [search for "Brockenhaus"](https://www.google.ch/search?sa=X&biw=1717&bih=926&q=brockenhaus+bern&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=46944237,7412914,1445&tbm=lcl&ved=0ahUKEwjuzLOQ27LOAhUHPxQKHZzUAD0QjGoIPg&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:2). The largest one I know of would probably be [this one](http://www.brocki.ch/filialen/bern/), though it's not as central as other ones.

Comment: There are no 'cheap stores' in Switzerland...

Comment: Voting to reopen. Not all shopping questions are bad. If you're in a generally expensive place and you need to buy something essential to your trip you need local knowledge expertise to find where the local non-rich would go to buy such a thing. Not everybody in Switzerland is rich. They have Lidl discount supermarkets. I'm sure they have some shops selling cheap Chinese stuff. Probably not in the financial or tourist districts. OP is not asking "lowest price for a Rolex in Switerland" - that's the bad kind of price-shopping question.